# how to make a pc to be connected with another pc directly, while still let it connect to the internet via network cable

Tags: networking, lan

I have my Windows PC which is connected to our LAN via a network cable, and through which I have access to the internet.

One of our teammates has no right to connect his Windows PC to our LAN.

Problem is that my teammate and I are now developing a web application, I build the backend and he build the frontend, and we need to communicate with each other through predefined http RESTful API.

I need to communicate with my teammate, while still can access our LAN.

What is the best practise to do so?

I tried to open a 360wifi, which can make my laptop pc to setup a Wi-Fi, and my teammate's laptop can access this Wi-Fi can visit the internet. But he cannot visit my backend service by the IP address of my laptop in the LAN network(ping returns error.).

I guess I need two network card, one for our LAN, another for my teammate, we can connect with each other via directly network cable connection.

Comment: What do you mean by "One of our teammates has no right to connect his Windows PC to our LAN."? Can you just get him the right?

Comment: @Albin it is hard to get him the right, or we can say get his pc the right. our LAN will recognize the mac address of his pc, and forbid him from the network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "best practice", there are just several options, it all depends on what you need.

- For a wired connection (better performance and stability): If you get a second network card (e.g. a USB network card) you can connect both PCs directly via a X-Ethernet cable or a switch. Depending on the setup of your LAN you also could connect the both PCs to a switch and the switch to you LAN.
- For a wireless connection (less performance/stability but you could use the existing WLAN adapters on the PCs): you could either connect both PCs to a hotspot (e.g. via an Android phone), via an access point or wireless router or via a WLAN ad hoc connection.

Comment: I tested the wireless connection solution on both android and iphone, both of them can work like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some of your options:

1. buy a network card
2. use a VPN
3. have the IT guy create a new network segment and firewall rules for your teammate so he can connect to you only
4. use a server in the cloud / over the internet and communicate with it
5. use a WiFi AP / router
6. use a WiFi hostspot software that does not block direct connections and make him create the WiFi since you're allowing him network access if you're creating it.